# .htaccess : allow download of Mercurial archive but only that

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mercurial

I was fairly happy with my Mercurial setup until now. I use it for personal projects and it is hosted on a shared server at OVH (a French hosting provider).

Currently, I have a .htaccess to protect my projects and only allow certain people to pull/push from my repositories. However, I would like to make the changesets archives public.

The URLs look like this :

```
http://domain/hg/projectname/archive/486e5be13c82.tar.bz2
http://domain/hg/projectname/archive/tip.tar.bz2
```

My .htaccess looks like this :

```
AuthUserFile /home/******/.hgusers
AuthName "Mercurial"
AuthType Basic

Order allow,deny
Allow from all

Require valid-user
```

And I would like to have the archive URLs to not ask a username/password. I don't mind using mod_rewrite for that. Thanks!

Remi Gillig.

Comment: I use OVH too! Great price and quality ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allow public access to all the changeset tarballs, then I suggest simply making the repository public (without allowing push, obviously). That is quite simple: `hg push` is done with a `POST` HTTP request, so you only need to `Require valid-user` for that. See also [the wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#Restrict_Pushing_to_Known_Users).

My thinking is that by giving people access to the tarballs, you have effectively given them access to the entire repository with the exception of the commit messages. So the cleanest solution is probably to just admit that and only restrict `hg push` :-)

Apart from that piece of wanna-be advice, I suggest you look at the [`<Location>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location) and `<LocationMatch>` directives if you have access to a system-wide configuration file for Apache (they cannot be put in a `.htaccess` file). I'm not a big Apache guru, so sorry for not giving you a ready-made rule you can insert.

Comment: Well, I didn't think about that before but maybe I could make another hgwebdir.cgi which displays only specific repositories under something like http://domain/hgpublic/. I don't want anyone to be able to access some private projects served under /hg/ so making all the repos public is not a viable solution for me. I will dig into modifiying the display script and report back.

Comment: OK, it works like a charm, I moved my public repos to a different directory and created a different hgweb.config to display only these. I now have 2 URLs : /hg for my private repos and /hg-public for my public repos. In /hg I even have the list of public repos so I don't have to modify the push URLs in hg when I push.

Comment: Cool, having two URLs sounds like a nice solution too (less magic than protecting only some of the URLs).